# Trim an array with respective to another array with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am handling a set of data recorded by a 2D detector. Therefore, the data are represented by three arrays: `x` and `y` labelling the coordinate of a pixel and `intensity` storing the measured signal.

For example, a 6x6 grid will give a set of data:

```
xraw = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,...])
yraw = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,...])
intensity = np.array([i_00,i_01,i_02,i_03,i_04,i_05,i_10,i_11,...])
```

Due to various reasons, such as pixel defects, some of the data points are discarded in the raw data. Therefore, `xraw, yraw, intensity` have a size smaller than 36 (if that's a 6x6 grid), with, say, the point at (2,3) missing.

The intensity data needs further treatment by an element-wise multiplication with another array. This treatment array is from theoretical calculation and so it has a size of nxn (6x6 in this case). However, as some of the points in the true data are missing, the two arrays have different sizes.

I can use a loop to check for the missing points and eliminate the corresponding element in the treatment array. I wonder if there are some methods in `numpy` that take care of such operations. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, construct the indices of available and all possible pixel positions by

```
avail_ind = yraw * h + xraw
all_ind = np.arange(0, h * w)
```

where `h` and `w` is the image's height and width in pixels.

Then, find the indices of the missing pixels by

```
missing_ind = all_ind[~np.in1d(all_ind, avail_ind)]
```

Once having the missing indices, use `np.delete` to construct a copy of the `treatment_array` with elements at the indices removed, then simply multiply that with your `intensity` array.

```
result = intensity * np.delete(treatment_array, missing_ind)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Yet, the missing pixels may vary from different measurements. Are there any shortcuts so that I can get the missing positions `x_missing, y_missing`?

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the additional requirements.

Comment: The implementation is elegant. Thank you!